# What is the covariance when you know the covariance w.r.t. a common variable?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance

Say you know that
${\rm var}\Bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
 {\bf x}_1 \\
 {\bf x}_2
\end{bmatrix}\Bigg) = {\bf \Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
{\bf \Sigma}_{11} & {\bf \Sigma}_{12}\\
{\bf \Sigma}_{21} & {\bf \Sigma}_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$
and that 
${\rm var}\Bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
 {\bf x}_2 \\
 {\bf x}_3
\end{bmatrix}\Bigg) = {\bf \Sigma}$
as well.
Then, what is the cross-covariance
${\rm cov}({\bf x}_1, {\bf x}_3)$?

You can assume all ${\bf x}_i$ are normally distributed and that ${\bf \Sigma}$ is a Toeplitz matrix, if that is helpful.

I have been chewing on this for days now, wrote a program in python that seems to confirm it is always one specific value, but I can't seem to find a formula.

Edit: there seems to be a missing equation. In my program, I also assume that $f({\bf x}_3 | {\bf x}_1, {\bf x}_2) = f({\bf x}_3 | {\bf x}_2)$. Does that additional constraint give a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question but there is no unique answer. The only constraint on $\Lambda=\text{cov}(\mathbf{x_1},\mathbf{x_2})$ is that the matrix
$$\left(\begin{matrix}\Sigma_{11} &\Sigma_{12} &\Lambda\\
\Sigma_{12}^T &\Sigma_{11} &\Sigma_{12}\\
\Lambda^T &\Sigma_{12}^T &\Sigma_{11}
\end{matrix}\right)$$
is positive definite.

**Note:** $\Sigma_{22}=\Sigma_{11}$ necessarily.

Comment: Hi, you are most definitely right. However, if you add the constraint $f({\bf x}_3 | {\bf x}_1, {\bf x}_2) = f({\bf x}_3 | {\bf x}_2)$, does that give a unique solution?

Comment: If you add this extra condition then, indeed, there is a single covariance matrix that fits.